# problem with Textmate and placing of cursor after end of line character

Tags: textmate

Maybe a simple question but I'm a little frustrated. I must have changed a setting in Textmate but can't seem to figure out what I have done. I can place the cursor in any place on a line even after a line break (can see the line break by showing invisibles). How do I set it so that it always goes back to end of line based upon new line character rather than anyplace in the line (including after the line break)?

For example, using the down arrow key will just place me into the line at textmate of where cursor was rather than at end of the current line.

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably enabled Freehand Editing without knowing. Go to *Edit - Mode - Freehanded Editing* and turn it off.

[image]

See the [Working With Text](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text) part of the TextMate manual for more info.

---

By the way: You can get a similar behavior from holding down <kbd>alt</kbd> and then clicking, which temporarily turns on the column-based editing mode. You can then click anywhere inside the document and the cursor will go there. Release <kbd>alt</kbd> and it is turned off again. It's actually a neat feature.